# Breaking down array columns into new sub-columns containing elements cut out from the parent column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I want to split an array in such a way that I can extract some sub-elements within the column, I am new to programming and in particular python, so please help...

```
say A = [['18x24x16']
         ['18x12x14']
         ['18x24x12']
         ['18x48x10']]
```

I want to have something like:

```
B = [['24' '16']
     ['12' '14']
     ['24' '12']
     ['48' '10']]
```

What function can I use and how?

Comment: What is `18x24x16`? New or old to programming, you could use few more words on explaining.

Comment: you are missing commas and what is the type of `18x24x16` ?

Comment: Also be clear - is this a numpy array, or a list of lists?

Comment: It's a numpy array, Those are like descriptions of 3D objects, for example length = 18, width = 24 and height = 16. I am reading those from a customers order, but to work on the real stuff, I need to extract the width and height alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is a list of strings, where each string is a list of numbers separated by any character `'x'`, you can use:

```
A = [['18x24x16'], ['18x12x14']]
B = [row[0].split('x') for row in A]
print(B)
# [['18', '24', '16'], ['18', '12', '14']]
```

Each element is still a string this way. If you want the actual numbers, use:

```
B = [[int(elem) for elem in row[0].split('x')] for row in A]
```

Use `int(elem)` if you want your values to all be integers, and `float(elem)` if you want them all to be floats (decimal-valued numbers).

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [
  [18, 24, 16],
  [18, 12, 14],
  [18, 24, 12],
  [18, 48, 10],
]

B = [[row[1] for row in A]]       # Each element is a list
B_prime = [row[1] for row in A]  # Each element is not a list.
```

Here's the documentation to help you on [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: Yours is a 4x3 array where you split the elements row-wise, but mine is a column array wherein I need to extract certain numbers from within rows with string data type.

Comment: My answer is for the question as it was asked at the time I answered it, before you edit it. You can't reproach me of answering wrongly a question that didn't even exist yesterday.

Comment: Very sorry about that. Hope you can still help